# Excel Return Max Text Value Using VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to come up with a formula in excel that will identify the max and min software offered on a computer and input it into a new table.

So for instance, in one large table I have column names like SKU, PRICE, PRODUCT FAMILY, SOFTWARE VERSION, etc.

In another table I have a list of PRODUCT FAMILY, and I need to identify the max/min software.

Software can be sorted in excel:

15.0(1)M2

15.0(1)M4

15.1(2)T1

15.1(2)T2

15.1(4)M3

15.1(4)M4

15.2(4)M3

But I cannot figure out how to return these as max/min values. Attempted Array Formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A4=Sheet1!$V$3:$V$644, Sheet1!$AE$3:$AE$644))
```

But this seems to be struggling with the non-numerical names. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand these values. What is the unit of "software"?

Comment: Its a name, but conventionally created in such a way that by sorting alphanumerically, the latest version should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

`MIN` only works on numerical values. You have to be a bit cleverer. I stole this formula from the [PC Review forum](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/find-min-value-excel-text-cells-t3836460.html):

`=INDEX(range,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(range,"<"&range),0))`

where `range` refers to your Software Version column. It doesn't seem to work if you specify a whole column (e.g. `A:A`).

It's an array formula, so <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd> it of course.

Comment: Just a quick clarification, I need this to first match the product family in a different sheet, and then return the minimum software version (so I'll need two different ranges...first to match product family, second to refer to the software column). Which range do I put where?

Comment: Use this formula wherever you think your `MIN` would go.